# Is possible to run different code depending on OS Language?

Tags: inno-setup

if installing different files depending on the language of the OS
(e.g. English Windows, Simplified Chinese Windows, Traditional Chinese
Windows, etc)? Will this be possible?

For Ex: I would like to do below :

```
[code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;  

if " OS Language is English" then begin
   MsgBox('This is English Version ?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2) = IDNO  
else if " OS Language is Traditional Chinese" 
   MsgBox('This is Traditional Chinese ?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2) = IDNO 
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [GetUILanguage](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getuilanguage.htm) support function to detect the OS language.

So you can code like this:

```
const
  LangEnglish = $09;
  LangSpanish = $0A;
  LangFrench = $0C;

if GetUILanguage and $3FF = LangEnglish then
  MsgBox('This is English Version!', mbInformation, MB_YES)
else if GetUILanguage and $3FF = LangSpanish then
  MsgBox('Esta es la versión en español!', mbInformation, MB_YES)
else if GetUILanguage = $0C01 then
  MsgBox('This is Arabic-Egypt Version!', mbInformation, MB_YES)
```

Documentation of: [language constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693.aspx)

Comment: Other options include using the `[Languages]` section to give the user a choice of languages for the installation itself (which defaults to the OS language, if available).  You can then condition specific installation entries via the `Languages:` parameter or specific text via `[CustomMessages]`.  Note also that some users may want multiple languages installed at the same time.